# how to return false if string has null or white space in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I cannot return null because my `Hlist` is a non nullable type. What else can I return in the place of null?

```
HList findHListentry(string letter)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(letter))
    {
        HList result = listentry.Find(delegate(HList bk)
                       {
                           return bk.letter == letter;
                       });
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        return ?;
    }
}
```

Comment: If `HList` is a value type, can you make it a nullable value type? `HList?`?

Comment: Somewhat related: I think your if condition logic is mixed up, based on the question title.

Comment: You can use a lamba instead of a delegate for a bit easier syntax: `return listEntry.Find( bk => bk.letter == letter );`

Comment: Do you have control over the definition of HList?  If not, you could wrap it with your own class definition adding an 'isNull' property.  Alternatively, if there is a value of HList that you know will never naturally occur initialize a readonly instance of it as your sentinel null value (sort of like DbNull).

Comment: The answers below are good, but the thing that really matters is what happens when this is called - how is the returned value handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input to the method truly *shouldn't* be `null` or an empty string, you could throw an exception:

```
HList findHListentry(string letter)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(letter))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("letter");

    HList result = listentry.Find(
        delegate(HList bk)
        {
            return bk.letter == letter;
        }
    );

    return result;
}
```

(Note that I also reversed the conditional logic, since it sounded like you were looking for the opposite from the title of the question.)

You can also look into [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808.aspx) to verify preconditions for methods instead of manually checking the input and throwing an exception.

Answer (score 5):

Use a `Nullable<HList>` instead?

```
HList? findHListentry(string letter)
{
    ///
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are several approaches of dealing with non-nullable value types:

- Using `Nullable<HList>` (the shorthand name for it is `HList?`), or
- Defining an "empty" `HList` entry, similar to how Microsoft defined one for `Guid`
- Make your method return `bool` instead of `HList`, and return `HList` through an `out` parameter, the way it is done in `Dictionary.TryGetValue`

Using a special value:

```
struct HList {
    public static HList Empty;
    ...
}

if (...) {
    return HList.Empty;
}
```

Returning `bool`:

```
bool findHListentry(string letter, out HList res) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

If `HList` is a struct:

1. Make it into a class intead. Then you can return null.
2. Change the method signature to `HList? findHListentry(string letter)`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [Nullable of T](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/05/27/143221.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you didnt want to return a null, you could create a static instance of HList that's used to indicate it's an 'empty' value.

Similar to EventArgs.Empty

`public static readonly HList EmptyHList = new Hlist() { /* initialise */ };`

Answer (score 0):

One implementation is to provide an Empty instance of the non-nullable type, and return that in place of null. Take string as an example...Whilst String is a nullable type in .NET, it contains a built in, readonly field called Empty, so with String you can do this:

```
if(mystring == null)
{
    //My String Is Null
}
```

or, you could do this

```
if(mystring == String.Empty)
{
    //My String is Empty
}
```

Whilst it is probably not the best approach, you could add an empty instance of HList to your class/struct. e.g.

```
HList findHListentry(string letter)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(letter))
    {
        HList result = listentry.Find(delegate(HList bk) { return bk.letter == letter; });
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        return HList.Empty;
    }
}

public struct HList
{
    public const HList Empty;
}
```

Now you can do this in place of null

```
if(myHList == HList.Empty)
{
    //My HList is Empty
}
```